# Subscription not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Network'

Tags: azure, networking, namespaces

While using azure vm`azure network public-ip create` I have encountered following error:

```
error:   The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Network'.
```

I have added a namespace to active directory on azure portal. However I cannot figure out how to configure it in order to work. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 32):

This is what helped me (through the Azure Portal).

1. Navigate to the Azure Portal
2. Under All Services, select Subscriptions
3. Select the subscription you are using
4. On the left menu, under Settings, select Resource Providers
5. Find the provider you need (Microsoft.Network) and click Register

I got these instructions from the following link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-register-provider-errors#solution-3---azure-portal

Comment: My error message was: "The subscription is not registered to use namespace
'Microsoft.Network'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to
register subscriptions.". This is a fix.

Comment: This works for Azure Students who want to configure Kubernetes!

Comment: This works for any resource that requires registration including Active Directory B2C & etc.